# Effects of merging a rebased branch in Git

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

***Background***

I want to retro-actively create a sub-project from my Git repo.

Currently, I have something like this...

```
A-B-C (origin/master)
```

I see now that a subset of this codebase would be useful for some other, similar, projects so I forked and deleted a bunch of stuff.

```
A-B-C-D (sub-project/master)
```

where commit `D` deletes a bunch of code that was specific to the `original/master` project.

Now I can create other projects from `sub-project/master`...

```
A-B-C-D-OP1 (other-project/master)
```

And, if I have general purpose updates (commits that I want to apply to all the other projects) I can make them to `sub-project/master` and then pull them into all my other projects...

```
A-B-C-D-E (sub-project/master)

A-B-C-D-OP1-E (other-project/master)
```

What I'd like to do now is to merge these same commits from `sub-project/master` back into `origin/master`, but I know that this will result in...

```
A-B-C-D-E (origin/master)
```

with `D` deleting a bunch of code from `origin/master`, when what I really want is...

```
A-B-C-E (origin/master)
```

***My Question***

If I rebase `sub-project/master`, removing commit `D`

```
A-B-C-E (sub-project/rebase-branch)
```

I know that I could then merge `sub-project/rebase-branch` into `original/master` so that it too will look like I want it to...

```
A-B-C-E (origin/master)
```

but what is going to happen if I then create additional commits on `sub-project`...

```
A-B-C-E-F (sub-project/rebase-branch)
```

and then merge `sub-project/rebase-branch` into `other-project/master`?

Will `other-project/master` result in this...?

```
A-B-C-D-OP1-E-F (other-project/master)
```

leaving `D` in place?

or will the merge result in this...?

```
A-B-C-OP1-E-F (other-project/master)
```

removing `D` when adding `F`?

If it's the former, then I'm good to go.
If it's the latter, then is there a viable solution to the dilemma I've outlined above?
(Is it possible for me to modify `sub-project` in such a way that I could then merge additional commits added to `sub-project` into both `origin/master` and into `other-project/master` - leaving `D` in-place in the latter, but absent in the former?)

Comment: Have you considered creating multiple repos rather than multiple branches?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @Code-Apprentice, I actually do have separate repos.  I've edited the question to try and better reflect my situation.

Comment: I think you are going about this all wrong. If you are refactoring out a library, your other projects should consume this the same way you would a third-party library. If it helps, pretend that the library is from a third-party. Make a binary release of the library and use **that** in the other projects. Don't try to merge the library into your other projects.

Comment: As my answer says, use gradle and/or maven to handle the dependencies.

Comment: To sum up my suggestion: treat your separate repos and **completely separate projects**; don't merge between them.

Comment: You can set up a filter-branch with a tree-filter to strip out the useless stuff from the entire history, do a bunch of rm --cached.  best is going to be to isolate the subset into a single subdir and make it a submodule

Answer (score 1):

As git has immutable history graph, when you do rebase, you just re-create same commits on top of different base. So, if you have history `A-B-C-D-E`, after rebase of `E` from `D` to `C` you'll get `A-B-C-E'`. If you merge it - it will have both commits in history `E` and `E'`.

So, it is possible to do, but I feel you are trying to use version control system as dependency management system, which is not the best thing to do. Try to reconsider how you use you components and separate them into independent projects.

Comment: "I feel you are trying to use version control system as dependency management system" That's what I understand as well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have found a subset of a project which can be spawned off as a library. You should maintain separate projects with completely separate repos (READ: no remotes set between each other). Make periodic "releases" of your library project that your other projects can use. You can use a tool such as gradle or maven to help you manage the dependency on your library project. Personally, I think this would be a better approach than trying to use git as a dependency management tool through merging commits.